# How to redirect to dashboard if user is logged in with AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new in AngularJS. I want to redirect my page to dashboard if user is logged in. After login, i am getting access token which I am saving in cookies. I checked the solutions of Stack Overflow, then also my problem is not solved.

Here is my code:

app.js

```
(function(window){

var app= angular.module('customersApp',['ngRoute','ngCookies','ui.bootstrap']);

app.config(['$routeProvider',
  function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
        when('/login', {
            title: 'Login',
            controller: 'loginController',
               templateUrl: 'app/views/loginuser.html'
        })
            .when('/logout', {
                title: 'Logout',
                templateUrl: 'partials/login.html',
                controller: 'loginController'
            })

            .when('/dashboard', {
                title: 'Dashboard',
                templateUrl: 'app/views/dynamic_table.html',
                controller: 'dashboard'
            })
            .when('/verified_artists', {
                title: 'Verified Artists',
                templateUrl: 'app/views/verified_artists.html',
                controller: 'artistController'
            })
            .when('/new_artists', {
                title: 'New Request Artists',
                templateUrl: 'app/views/new_artists.html',
                controller: 'artistController'
            })

            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/login'
            });
  }]);
   window.app = app;

}(window));
```

loginController.js

```
app.controller('loginController', function ($scope,$http,$cookies,$cookieStore) {


    //initially set those objects to null to avoid undefined error
    $scope.login = {};
    $scope.signup = {};
    $scope.doLogin = function (customer) {


  $.post("websiteurl.com/admin_login",
  {

     user_email : $scope.login.email,
      password : $scope.login.password

  },


  function(data,status){

      data = JSON.parse(data);
      console.log(data);

    var someSessionObj = { 'accesstoken' : data.access_token};

    $cookies.dotobject = someSessionObj;
    $scope.usingCookies = { 'cookies.dotobject' : $cookies.dotobject, "cookieStore.get" : $cookieStore.get('dotobject') };

    $cookieStore.put('obj', someSessionObj);
    $scope.usingCookieStore = { "cookieStore.get" : $cookieStore.get('obj'), 'cookies.dotobject' : $cookies.obj, };

    console.log($cookieStore.get('obj').accesstoken);

     if(data.flag==10)
      {
          alert(data.error);
      }
      else
      {
         window.location.href = "#/dashboard";

      }


  })


    };


});
```

Comment: You want to redirect to dashboard, when some logged in user opens your webpage again. is my understanding correct? Also is the above code working?

Comment: yes, if user is logged in, then it will not go back to login page until i am not clicking on log out button

Comment: use 
`app.run(['$cookieStore', function ($cookieStore) {
// check for cookie here if present redirect to dashboard           
}])`

Answer (score 0):

try to look for route change event and check for cookie using cookie store...

```js
$rootScope.$on( "$routeChangeStart", function(event, next, current) {
  // check for the cookie 
  // if present 
    // check next route
        // if its login/signup page
        // event.preventDefault(); (don't make the route change, redirect to dashboard)
        // $location.path("/dashboard");
        
        // if it is some other route
        // allow it.
  
  // if cookie not present
  // $location.path("/login");
});
```